# Creating smart model in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I want to create an `ActiveRecord`-like interface for Salesforce, such that I can call

```
class Account < Salesforce::Model

end
```

and be able to call methods like `Account.find_by_FirstName()` using my own `method_missing` function.

However, connecting to Salesforce can be done in two ways: username and password, and oauth.  If a username/password is used, I can have it defined in a `salesforce.yml` file and load automatically. But with oauth, I can't do that since each user will have this defined. I don't want to initialize a class with `Account.new('oauth', oauth_parmas)` or `Account.new('username','password','sec_token')`, but have the model determine which to use based off of rules and by seeing if one or the other is present.

Is there a way to implement this? In other words, is there a way for the model to know if the current user has a current `oauth` token or if a username/password defined?

Additionally, if I were to use this in a Rails app, the user would be logging in after the app was started, so the `oauth` token would be defined after the application started, and would be different for each of the multiple users. For example, let's say I call `Account.find_by_FirstName('John')` in `AccountController#Show`. I want the Account model to use the `oauth` token or usename/password without having to be asked. I also don't want to establish connection directly in my `show` method in the controller. I have two questions:

1. How would I implement this? Should I use a `before_filter` in the controller, or is there a way to implement this application-wide?
2. If I have multiple users connecting to Salesforce, would this cause issues in my application? In other words, would I have to worry about a connection being used by another user since the connection is dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your needing is not different from `ActiveRecord::Base` connection establishment: you establish the connection using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and every model you use after the connection establishment know which connection to use, because you memorized the connection at superclass level.

For Salesforce you can use the same concept:

```
class Salesforce::Model
  def self.oauth_params
    @oauth_params
  end
  def self.establish_connection(oauth_params)
    @oauth_params = oauth_params
  end
  def self.find(id)
    # use oauth_params here 
  end
end

class Account < Salesforce::Model
end
```

Now you can do something like

```
Salesforce::Model.establish_connection ['username', 'password']
Account.find 2 # without specifying authentication params
```

---

Since you know authentication params after knowing the logged user, you can establish the connection after the user is logged:

```
def sign_user
  # user = ...
  oauth_params = get_oauth_params(user)
  Salesforce::Model.establish_connection(oauth_params)
end
```

### Concurrency (threads)

> *If I have multiple users connecting to Salesforce, would this cause issues in my application? In other words, would I have to worry about a connection being used by another user since the connection is dynamic?*

Legitimate question. If you run the Rails application in a threaded environment (threaded application server - f.e. [Puma](http://puma.io/), multi-threaded architecture - JRuby, Rubinius...) AND Rails is configured as threadsafe (`config.threadsafe!`), you could have concurrency problems (the explanation is not trivial - check out [this](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html)).

If this is your case you can scope the `@oauth_params` variable accessor to `Thread.current`:

```
class Salesforce::Model

  @oauth_params = { Thread.current => nil }

  def self.oauth_params
    @oauth_params[Thread.current]
  end

  def self.establish_connection(oauth_params)
    @oauth_params[Thread.current] = oauth_params
  end
```

> Would it be possible that the thread for the current user changes?

It is possible, if some code you execute runs inside a new thread. F.e.:

```
Salesforce::Model.establish_connection(oauth_params)
Thread.new{ p Salesforce::Model.oauth_params }.join #=> puts nil
```

In this case you have to reestablish the connection in the new thread (I can do it just if you need it).

> I could request something on thread 1 and complete that request, but afterwards, someone else uses thread 1 and I have to use thread 2. Is this possible?

Thinking about it, you need to reset the variable at the beginning of the call in order to avoid that the next request uses the params set in any previous request:

```
before_action :reset_connection, :sign_user

def reset_connection
  Salesforce::Model.establish_connection(nil)
end

def sign_user
  # ...
```

Comment: I added an additional couple questions and more information regarding my specific use case. Would you be able to update your answer to reflect my update?

Comment: That's correct. Each user would use his/her `oauth` params, and would request the resource from Salesforce in Rails.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if something is not clear (my english is poor)

Comment: Would it be possible that the thread for the current user changes? I.e. I could request something on thread 1 and complete that request, but afterwards, someone else uses thread 1 and I have to use thread 2. Is this possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38175/discussion-between-joshua-smock-and-prognommers)